# How can I redirect linux terminal output to Eclipse console?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, terminal, console

I am trying to redirect Terminal output to Eclipse console using external tools where I specified Terminal path (for example `/usr/bin/xterm`). When I run this tool it opens Terminal outside eclipse. When I did same thing in Windows 7, setting external tool location to `Windows\System32\cmd.exe` it ran inside Eclipse console. I wonder how I can make Terminal (in Ubuntu 14.04) work the same way.

Comment: `/usr/bin/xterm` is explicit request for external window. Try running the program _without_ prepending `/usr/bin/xterm` or try using `/bin/sh`. Note that `xterm` is _not_ equivalent to windows `cmd.exe`. `cmd.exe` mixes two functionalities: interpreting commands, which in Unix is job of `/bin/sh`, and opening terminal window, which in X-Windows is job of `/usr/bin/xterm` or `/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator`.

Comment: If it worked, I'll make it a proper answer, so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/bin/sh` as command interpreter.

In Windows, `cmd.exe` combines two functions—interpreting commands and displaying terminal window. In Unix these functions are strictly separated. `/bin/sh` interprets commands and `/usr/bin/xterm` (or `/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator`) displays terminal window, inside which it runs `/bin/sh` (or other shell like `/bin/bash`, `/bin/zsh` etc.) to interpret commands.

So if you ask Eclipse to run something via `/usr/bin/xterm`, it will appear in a new window, because that's what XTerm does. If you just want Eclipse to capture the output, ask it to run it directly via `/bin/sh`.